# How to randomly get 0 or 1 every time?

Tags: python, random

**Display matrix of 0s and 1s**

> Write a function that displays an n-by-n matrix using the following
> header:
>
> ```
> def printMatrix(n):
> ```
>
> Each element is `0` or `1`, which is generated randomly. Write a test
> program that prompts the user to enter n and displays an `n`-by-`n`
> matrix. Here is a sample run:
>
> ```
> Enter n: 3 
> 010 
> 000 
> 111
> ```

Here is my idea:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from random import randint, choice

import random

n = input ("Enter an interger number:")
k = randint(0, 1)
for i in range (1, n+1):
    for j in range (1, n+1):
        print (format((i*j)/(i*j)*k, "3d") , end = '')
    print ()
```

Comment: And this isn't working... **how**?

Comment: At a glance, I'm guessing it always prints either a 3x3 thing of all zeroes, or a 3x3 thing of all ones. I think OP wants a mixture of zeroes and ones.

Comment: You need to pick a `randint` *inside the loop*.

Comment: I have no idea do a randint inside the loop. Do you have any example codes?

Comment: Well, you know how you have `randint` outside the loop? Move it inside.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but what are you trying to do with `i` and `j`? `(i*j)/(i*j)` is just `1`. There's really no need for `i` and `j` at all from where I'm standing.

Comment: why did you remove your attempt? without your own code this isn't a decent question

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that your code generates a single value and then prints it repeatedly. A simplified version of the problem would be this:

```
k = random.randint(0, 1) # decide on k once
for _ in range(n):
    print(k) # print k over and over again
```

This will generate `k`, then print it `n` times, but what you want is to generate a new value to print each time

```
for _ in range(n):
    k = random.randint(0, 1) # decide on a k each time the loop runs
    print(k)
```

---

You can generate the matrix itself using a nested list comprehension (which may be more than you want to know at this point, but worth showing)

```
[[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

the inner part `[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(n)]` will give you `n` values in the range 0-1.  nesting that in another comprehension gives you `n` of those.

Answer (score 5):

```
from random import randint
n = int(input ("Enter an interger number:"))
matrix = (
    [str(randint(0, 1)) for _ in range(0, n)] for _ in range(0, n)
)
for row in matrix:
    print "".join(row)
```

FYI. check this documentation about [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Can do function for that?

Comment: Yes, with an absolute basic knowledge of Python everyone can put this code in a function without any problems. Why do you ask?

Comment: `''.join([random.choice(['0', '1']) for i in range(n)])`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ryan H's answer to get the count of the 0s and 1s in case anyone came here looking to do basic statistics (applying the square root law - Coursera)

```py
count_0 = 0
count_1 = 0
list_2 = [[random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(1)]
#the 100 stands for 100 random numbers to be generated
for x in list_2[0]:
    if x > 0:
        count_0 = count_0 + 1
    else:
        count_1 = count_1 + 1
print (f"count of 1s is {count_1}")
print (f"count of 0s is {count_0}")
```

Answer (score 0):

myself not being deep into the theory random theory....this answer below works fine for my purposes...else checkout this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-random-number-generators-for-machine-learning/) for the theory.

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    my_random_float = random.random()

    if my_random_float > .5:
        my_rand_int = 1
    else:
        my_rand_int = 0

    print(my_rand_int)
```

this prints:

```
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def printMatrix(n):

        return n + 0


def main():

     n = int(input ("Enter an interger number:"))

    matrix = ([str(randint(0, 1)) for _ in range(0, n)] for _ in range(0, n))

    for row in matrix:

         print(" ".join(row))

main()
```